# Maven Compilation error when running mvn test command in cmd

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELgPO.jpg)When i am using mvn complie it is giving me build success but when i am using mvn test i am getting compiler failure.

1) I have added mvn compiler dependencies in pom xml
2) changed the value in scope node from test to compile
3) Checked Java_Home path which is directing to JDK 1.8

Comment: Please add some further details. What exactly do you mean by "compiler failure"? Is there a stacktrace given? Can you share the code that leads to this problem?

Comment: Hello Sir, i have added an image. I am getting the bellow error when i am running the command mvn test from command line " Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project my-app: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:"C:/Users/syed/my-app/src/test/java/com/mycompany/app/AppiumTest.java:[3,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Test
[ERROR]   location: package org.testng.annotations

Comment: Please don't add images when text can also provide the same information. Additionally, add all relevant information to the question by editing it, not to the comment section